# How load a website offline as a iOS app

Tags: html, ios, iphone

This emulator has a nice feature, when you click in the "share in home screen" option, it works as a app, offline and out of a browser.

https://gameplaycolor.com/app/

I intend make something like it, but I have no idea how can I do. Which technique it website use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Placing websites on the homescreen is native iOS. As a website, you can extend this, by enabling your website as a 'web app', like you described. For this, you use a number of meta tags in your code. Please see [this support document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) by Apple on how to configure your website so users can save it to their homescreen as a web app.

Moreover, you can specify a startup screen, the color of the statusbar, and some other things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It also works and load iframes ?

Comment: @user3245085 it should do everything a normal website can. But loading content like an iframe will require an Internet connection

Comment: and you know an alternative for that?

Comment: @user3245085 a web "app" still loads the data from the website. To my knowledge you cannot save data as a web app offline. It is like a shortcut to the website, but instead of opening the default browser it opens as an app but shows the website.

Comment: @user3245085 you can check it yourself, if you save any website (like your example) which is setup as a web app and then open it from the homescreen, you have to wait for the website to load.